# Handling Spill on shinydashboard

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I haven't gotten any responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34258868/dynamically-changing-shiny-element-dimensions) so here's a simpler question. Any way to get the `fluidRow` container to resize along with the plot? I would expect that moving the slider to very high values would add a scrollbar to the shiny window but nothing happens and the plot just spills over from the bottom of the screen.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(
      title = "Sidebar spill"

   ),
   dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
         menuItem(text = "Something")
         )
      ),
   dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
         sliderInput(label = 'sizeplot', inputId = 'sizeplot', min = 100, max = 1200, value = 400 )
      ),
      fluidRow(
         plotOutput('qwe')
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output[['qwe']] = renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars) +
         geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg))
      },
      height = exprToFunction(input$sizeplot))
}

shinyApp(ui, server,)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi if you specify the height in the ui it seems to work :

```
plotOutput('qwe', height = "100%")
```

By default the div created by `plotOutput` have a fixed height (400px) and changing the plot height in the server does not affect this one, so the image just override the content below.